# using setInterval and clearInterval to change counter in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-state

I'm trying to create an application with a 'bathtub' and 2 buttons.  The tub has 5 levels of water.
When you click the first button, the tub fills one level every 2 seconds until reaching 5.  The other button drains the tub until level 0.  The increaseWaterLevel and decreaseWaterLevel functions are only firing once and I'm not sure why.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [waterLevel, setWaterLevel] = useState(0);
  let fillTub;
  let drainTub;
  const increaseWaterLevel = () => {
    if (waterLevel < 5) {
      const newWaterLevel = waterLevel + 1;
      setWaterLevel(newWaterLevel);
    } else {
      clearInterval(fillTub);
    }
  };

  const decreaseWaterLevel = () => {
    if (waterLevel > 0) {
      const newWaterLevel = waterLevel - 1;
      setWaterLevel(newWaterLevel);
    } else {
      clearInterval(fillTub);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Bathtub</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fillTub = window.setInterval(increaseWaterLevel, 2000);
        }}
      >
        increaseWaterLevel
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          drainTub = window.setInterval(decreaseWaterLevel, 2000);
        }}
      >
        decreaseWaterLevel
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

update the counter is working but does not stop and waterLevel remains at 0.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [waterLevel, setWaterLevel] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

  const increaseWaterLevel = () => {
    const newWaterLevel = setInterval(() => {
      if (waterLevel > 4) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      } else {
        setWaterLevel((prevWaterLevel) => prevWaterLevel + 1);
      }
    }, 2000);
    setIntervalId(newWaterLevel);
  };

  const decreaseWaterLevel = () => {
    const newWaterLevel = setInterval(() => {
      if (waterLevel > 0) {
        setWaterLevel((prevWaterLevel) => prevWaterLevel - 1);
      } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 2000);
    setIntervalId(newWaterLevel);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Bathtub</div>
      <button onClick={increaseWaterLevel}>increaseWaterLevel</button>
      <button onClick={decreaseWaterLevel}>decreaseWaterLevel</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: look here , to understand how to use setInterval and clearInterval
https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react/

Comment: It was a good tutorial!  But I'm still a little confused.  My setInterval is not keeping track of state change so it counts infinitely.

Comment: @Gareth check my answer and then do some research like "How to get updated variable after setState". It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let me first say that i started learning react like 1 week ago and i
> still have some doubt and this code may be really bad even if it
> works, but i still want to help so this is the code.

The main problem here is that `useState` function is an **async** function and it doesn't update in real time your variable so in this case checking waterLevel value without `useEffect` will not work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
const [waterLevel, setWaterLevel] = useState(0);
const [actionType, setActionType] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (actionType == "increase" && waterLevel < 5)
      setWaterLevel(waterLevel + 1);
    if (actionType == "decrease" && waterLevel > 0)
      setWaterLevel(waterLevel - 1);
  }, 2000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [actionType, waterLevel]);

return (
   <div>
   <div>Bathtub</div>
   <button onClick={() => setActionType("increase")}>
     increaseWaterLevel
   </button>
   <button onClick={() => setActionType("decrease")}>
     decreaseWaterLevel
   </button>
   <h1>{waterLevel}</h1>
 </div>
 );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: ActionTypes are a really good way of doing this!  Your solution works quite well, and I will definitely have to read up on useEffect in this context.  Thank you everyone, for your contributions!

Comment: @Gareth If so close the answer by accepting it, I’m glad I was able to help you